# Using std::lower_bound for first true in predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

Let’s say our goal is to minimise the number of steps used overall to do something and in the scope of the algorithm implementation we’d invent `is_possible_in_less_than_k_steps(Args const& args, int k);`

And it is obvious that returns have a partition point before which returns are 0, and after which returns would be 1.

Is there a way to use STL algorithms to perform a bin search of the solution?

Tried reinventing the wheel, but that doesn’t look good to me.

```cpp
unsigned l = min, r = max;
while (l < r)
{
    unsigned m = (l + r) >> 1;
    bool possible = is_possible_in_less_than_k_steps(args, m);
    if (!possible)
    {
        l = m + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        r = m;
    }
}
return l;
```

Comment: It's not "obvious" how the `is_it_possible` function behaves. If its output can be considered ordered for all values of `m` that are also ordered, then you can use binary search routines like [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound). These functions accept a custom comparator which you can use to find the point where the output of `is_it_possible` changes. Provided it only changes at most once in the entire sequence.

Comment: A more appropriate choice might be [`std::partition_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point)

Comment: @paddy other than the predicate, is there any difference between `lower_bound` and `partition_point`?

Comment: @paddy it is obvious, since `is_possible_in_less_than_k_steps(args, int k);` is named so. If something is possible in less than k steps, then it is also possible in less than k+1 steps. In the same way, if something is not possible in less than k steps, it’s also not possible in less than k-1 steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++20 ranges this is fairly trivial:

```
auto range = std::ranges::views::iota(min, max);
auto partition_point = std::ranges::partition_point(
    range,
    [&](unsigned i) { return !is_it_possible(args, i); }
);
if (partition_point == std::ranges::end(range)) {
    // no partition point found
} else {
    // *partition_point is the value you're looking for
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bd11e42e78d7fac)